# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(-y)^n/n!]D^n \exp(-2 \pi x^2)=\exp[-2\pi(x-y)^2]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to show that

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(-y)^n/n!]D^n \exp(-2 \pi x^2)=\exp[-2\pi(x-y)^2]$,

where $D$ is the differential operator. From the Taylor expansion we know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!=\exp(x)$. My first attempt was to simply write:

$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(-y)^n/n!]D^n \exp(-2 \pi x^2)=\exp(-2 \pi x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(-yD)^n/n!]
$

$
= \exp(-2 \pi x^2)\exp(-yD),
$

but that didn't seem to work which I guess is because we cannot treat $\exp(-2 \pi x^2)$ as a constant. I'm not too familiar with the the differential operator in infinite sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't commute a differential operator with a function; if the operator is on the left (right), the result is a function (operator). (One could (mis)identify a function $g$ with the operator $h\mapsto gh$, but that still won't justify what you've tried.) But $\color{blue}{\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-y)^n}{n!}D^n}f(x)=f(x-y)$ is just a Taylor series in $f$, construed as a function of $-y$, expanded at $x$. The choice $f(z):=\exp(-2\pi z^2)$ meets all the differentiability requirements for this to be rigorous. In particular, you don't need to spot the blue part is $e^{-yD}$ for this argument.

Answer (score 1):

The differential operator against the gaussian can be expressed in terms of Hermite polynomials,
$$
\mathcal {D}_n e^{-2\pi x^2}=\frac{d^n e^{-2\pi x^2}}{dx^n}=(-1)^n(2\pi)^n H_n(2\pi x)e^{-2\pi x^2}
$$
You can prove this by induction.  The sum becomes,
$$
S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\pi y)^n H_n(2\pi x)e^{-2\pi x^2}}{n!}=e^{-2\pi x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\pi y)^n H_n(2\pi x)}{n!}
$$
The exponential generating function can be expressed in terms of Hermite polynomials,
$$
e^{2xt-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_n(x)t^n}{n!}
$$
Setting
$$
t=2\pi y
$$
the desired result is obtained.

Comment: Thank you. The questions is asked in the context of Hermite functions so your approach is helpful.